# Swagger.json error: Structural error at paths./api/v1/create.post.consumes should NOT have duplicate items (items ## 11 and 15 are identical)

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-editor

I have following api method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/v1/create")]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody]CreationDto dto)
```

after i add [FromBody], the swagger.json file has error:
 Structural error at paths./api/v1/create.post.consumes should NOT have duplicate items (items ## 11 and 15 are identical)

```
 consumes:
        - application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true
        - application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false
        - application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
        - application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true
        - application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false
        - application/json;odata.metadata=full
        - application/json;odata.metadata=none;odata.streaming=true
        - application/json;odata.metadata=none;odata.streaming=false
        - application/json;odata.metadata=none
        - application/json;odata.streaming=true
        - application/json;odata.streaming=false
        - application/json
        - application/xml
        - application/prs.mock-odata
        - application/json-patch+json
        - application/json
        - text/json
        - application/*+json
```

if I remove it, the error missing.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like this should be fixed in the latest version of Swashbuckle - https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/942

Answer (score 0):

One Content-Type exists twice:

```
- application/json
```

Just remove one of them.
This content-type exists in as item #11 and #15 starting with #0.